# How to generate documentation with godoc correctly?

Tags: go

Here is my code and terminal window. What should I do to make it work well and return function description?

```
// Copyright DOCUMENTATION FOR ME. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style
// license that can be found in the LICENSE file.
package testDoc

// sayHello return "Hello world string"
func sayHello() string{
    return "Hello world!"
}
```

[terminal return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGFk3.png)

Comment: You did not export your function (make it accessible outside your package), hence it is not covered by Godoc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the -u flag to show [unexported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) symbols: `go doc -u ./test`